# Order nodes by comment_count

Tags: nodes, database

I try to order nodes title by `->comment_count`..
the code below: using `db_select` :

```
function odrer_node_by_comment_count($type) {
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->join('comment', 'c' , 'c.nid=n.nid');
  $query->join('node_comment_statistics', 'ncs', 'ncs.nid=n.nid');
  $query->fields('n', array('title'))
   ->condition('n.type', $type, '=')
   ->condition('c.status', 1 , '=')
   ->orderBy('ncs.comment_count', 'DESC');

   $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

   if (isset($result)) {
     foreach ($result as $node) {
       return $node->title;
     }
   }
}
```

The issue here is node title return more than one..
Then I use `db_query`:

```
function odrer_node_by_comment_count($type) {
 $result = db_query('SELECT c.nid AS nid 
    FROM {comment} c 
    JOIN {node_comment_statistics} ncs ON ncs.nid = c.nid
    WHERE c.status = 1
    ORDER BY ncs.comment_count DESC')->fetchAllKeyed();

   if (isset($result)) {
     foreach ($result as $node) {
       return $node->title;
     }
   }
}
```

It works fine,, But i don't know how to pass the $type into query..

Answer (score 0):

No code needed, i have not try this but i think it works, create a view of comments (not nodes), order them by number of comments, and a relationship to the parent node of comment, then modify each field in display settings to use the relationship to the parnet node, this will display the node instead of the comment. that's it.

Comment: I can handle it by view.. but i need it code ?

Comment: you do NOT need any code, just buit your view with views UI. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVwclF9TfBo

Comment: is it possible to do it using code? "yes", how?